# BeautifulSoup: How to get publish datetime of a youtube video in datwtime format?

Tags: python, datetime, beautifulsoup, youtube, datetime-format

In one portion of my crawler, I need to scrape the published time and date in the datetime format of a youtube video. I am using bs4 and so far I can get the published time format just the way YT GUI shows to us i.e. "published on 6th may, 2017". But I cannot retrieve the actual datetime. How can I do this?

**My code :**

```
    video_obj["date_published"] = video_soup.find("strong", attrs={"class": "watch-time-text"}).text
    return video_obj["date_published"]
```

**The output:**

```
Published on Feb 8, 2020
```

**The way I want:**

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get:

```
Published on Feb 8, 2020
```

You can do following to remove "Published on"

```
date_string = soup_string.strip("Published on")
```

To get this in format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS you can use python-dateutil library in python. You can install it using:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Code:

```
from dateutil import parser
formatted_date = parser.parse("Published on Feb 8, 2020", fuzzy=True)
```

This will output date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

[You can read more about python-dateutil parser here](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pythons datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse the String and Format the output.

```
pubstring = video_obj["date_published"]  # "Published on Feb 8, 2020"
# pubstring[:13] cuts of first 13 chars
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(pubstring[13:], "%b %d, %Y")
return dt.strftime("%F") # Format as needed
```